# How can I make the gtk2 font the same as gtk3?

Tags: fonts

For some reason, the gtk2 font is different than it was some time ago. I haven't touched it, I can't remember what were the circumstances, but it has changed.

Here's a screenshot of gedit (gtk3) and firefox (gtk2) side to side:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw2eM.png

Thanks for your kind help.
Note: I also haven't found anything font-related in the settings, apart from the Large Text setting in Universal Access. Is there a way to change the size of the font? Everything is too big by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, turns out this wasn't a "gtk2" problem, but a firefox and thunderbird problem. Only happened with them. What I did is I deleted the $HOME/.config/fontconfig folder and now everything's back to normal. I'm not sure as of why, but it works.